# QGLWidget ignores glClear

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

I'm stumped. I have a widget inside the mainwindow on a QT 4.6 application which has been configured as a openGL widget. It draws just fine except I am unable to clear the background between frames. I get a black background when he window opens and it never clears after that, so I get a jumbled mess of rendered objects as time goes along. I'm also having to call swapBuffers() at the end of the paintGL() function to get the widget to show the most recent frame which has me puzzled as I was under the impression that swapBuffers() was called automatically. I am set up for double buffering and the widget is not shared. Here is the relevant code:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL ( )
{
    m_Input.Draw();
    QGLWidget::swapBuffers();
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL ( )
{
    qglClearColor(QColor(0,0,255,128));
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

It does seem there's something not right with the double buffering. Clearing the screen to a background color is pretty basic. But it's driving me nuts as to why it's not working. The remainder of the drawing code is working fine. Any ideas? (This is on a Linux system.)

Answer (score 2):

`glClear` is a drawing operation. It doesn't belong into `initializeGL` but into `paintGL`. The clearing color should be set right before calling `glClear` as well, so move that  `[q]glClearColor` along.

#### Update

The paintGL method should look like this:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    qglClearColor(QColor(0,0,255,128));
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // you probably also want to clear the depth and stencil buffers
    // glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    m_Input.Draw();

    QGLWidget::swapBuffers();
}
```

Of course you must make sure that `m_Input.Draw()` doesn't mess things up again. You didn't show the code for that, so I'm in the blind here.

Comment: I understand that. The glClear has been moved all over the place. No matter where it's placed (inside glInitialize, glPaint, or inside the drawing routines) it gets ignored. The code shown was based on a guess that because Qt is doing a lot of other drawing that it intercepts the glClear call and does it on it's own based on what you told it in the glInitialize routine. No success with that idea either.

Comment: @QuickGrip: Qt intercepts nothing and glClear belongs into the `paintGL` method. I can't tell it "nicer", but you're probably using it wrong. Order of operations matter, see my code outline.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I tried the exact code you posted. It doesn't work. I've tried placing glClear in just about every place you can put it. It has no effect no matter where it's called, and that's the problem.

Comment: @QuickGrip: When you say "it doesn have an effect", what is your desired output and what do you get instead? (screenshots would be great). Also seeing the code of the `???::Draw` method would be great.

Comment: For now, I would like it to clear the screen to the color specified in glClearColor. The code in ::Draw just sets the view matrices and draws a wire frame model. I could post a screen a screenshot, but all you're going to see is a black background with a mess of lines from the wire frame model being drawn and not cleared between frames.